# Wood pecker damage on Pecan tree

Tags: tree-care

My pecan tree has hundreds of holes, apparently made by a woodpecker. What is the best treatment to assure that no other damage from fungus or other infestation is incurred on the tree?

Comment: We need few photo. I suspect that the tree is not going well: such trees are a trove for insects and for eaters of insects.

Answer (score 2):

The wood peckers are not damaging your tree, they are eating the dudes that ARE damaging your tree. Certainly doesn't help the pecking I mean but your tree has an insect infestation. That is why the wood pecker is drilling; there are a lot of juicy larva beneath the bark and those larvae are what is possibly going to kill your tree. I would get an arborist or your Cooperative Extension Service to ID and diagnose. Very inexpensive it might save your tree.

You could send more pictures we most certainly could identify your problem but you really need someone testing your tree that knows the local flora, fauna and soils. Those birds can HEAR the little larvae wiggling around under the bark.  Isn't that amazing?  They would NOT be drilling if there was a chance of coming up dry.